# Can field in form autopopulate based on other field's drop down selection? Both fields are from the same list

Tags: list, column, form, dropdown

I have a form that's pulling in items from different columns of this list:![List][1]
On the form, you have the option to select Job Title and, later on the form, Systems Access, ![Categories][2]
Since these two columns are from the same list, is there a way to have the corresponding Systems Access automatically populate in the Systems Access drop down when a Job Title is selected in the Job Title drop down?
Thank you!

EDIT: I tried adding this code to the NewForm.aspx in SP Designer, but it didn't work:

```
<script language="javascript" src="/JSLibrary/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript">  
</script> <script language="javascript" src="/JSLibrary/jquery.SPServices-0.5.7.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">  

  $(document).ready(function() {  

            $().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({  

                relationshipList: "SystemsAccess",  

                relationshipListParentColumn: "JobTitle",  

                relationshipListChildColumn: "SystemsAccess",  

                parentColumn: "JobTitle",  

                childColumn: "SystemsAccess",  

                promptText: "Choose State...",  

                debug: true  

            });  

});  
</script>
```

(images removed)

Comment: A few options, Infopath, custom JS you create yourself, or as part of http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=$().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns&referringTitle=Documentation

Answer (score 0):

You can handle select tag change event using JavaScript and inside that handler use JavaScript Object Model to read list values and set the second select input.

Comment: Steps?  I need help with this.  Thanks.